# A few XmlElement attributes on a property C#

Tags: c#, xml

Can I have more than one XmlElement on property of a class? 
For example:

```
[XmlElement("name")]
[XmlElement("clientName")]
public string Name { .. }
```

I need this for deserialization. Let's say that the Name element in the XML file will be named "name" or "clientName". I want to achieve some kind of flexibility (to list the possible names for the xml element which correspond to the Name attribute.

The main idea is that I have to import XML files from another program and I have to make some kind of "templates for import".

Comment: This seems wrong. Why do you want 2 Xml values related to a single property?

Comment: what does the compiler say?   Also why would you want to do that.  Try phrasing this as a problem you are trying to solve and this is the code I have tried and doesn't work.

Comment: did you try it out to see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is actually yes, but only under certain conditions. If you want a different element name for different types, you can do that. As for no type specified, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) says nothing.

```
[XmlElement(typeof(int),
 ElementName = "ObjectNumber"),
XmlElement(typeof(string),
 ElementName = "ObjectString")]
public ArrayList ExtraInfo;
```

Answer (score 4):

Guessing that you need to import XML with two different element names for the same value  you could do this:

```
  string _Name;

  [XmlElement("name")]
  public string Name {
    get {
      return _Name;
    }
    set {
      _Name = value;
    }
  }

  [XmlElement("clientName")]
  public string ClientName {
    get {
      return _Name;
    }
    set {
      _Name = value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will work if you can guarantee that your source data will contain either a name element or a clientName element, but not both.  Otherwise, if both elements exist and have different values, this approach will cause trouble.

Comment: @phoog: agreed - if the XML contains both elements you cannot control which one 'wins'. I am guessing tha the XML will contain one or the other elements but not both - but the question is not very clear on this.